# MacOS X equivalent for VerQueryValue?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, fileversioninfo

I am currently porting a project to MacOS, and in the Windows version we use  [VerQueryLang(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464(v=vs.85).aspx), which is part of winapi, to determine some file version information for the window title.

Is there an equivalent function on MacOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's built into the app's bundle:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *version = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString *build = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html).